# How to get the arrays inside an array which is in the form of string using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am pretty new to java and javascript and I have a problem.

I have an array in the form of a string which looks like below in javascript.

```
[[0,'Apple','Banana'],['The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree', 'The Banana fruit, comes from Banana Tree']]
```

In this, I need to get the first array `[0,'Apple','Banana']` and save it as a separate array and then I need to get the second array `['The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree', 'The Banana fruit, comes from Banana Tree']` and display it as a text in text area like this.

> The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree
> The Banana fruit, comes from
>   Banana Tree

How can I achieve this in javascript?

Please need some help as I have googled about this problem intensively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: eval this string so it will be converted to array. Then you can easily access.

Comment: No - don't `eval` it - it's seriously bad practice and it's not necessary.

Comment: @ShuklaJay - Depending on where the string value comes from, using `eval` can be very unsafe. Much better to use `JSON.parse(string)` to turn this into an array.

Comment: BTW, the plant that bananas grow on is not a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you have a string.

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[[0,'Apple','Banana'],['The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree', 'The Banana fruit, comes from Banana Tree']]");

var seprateArr = arr[0];

var text = arr[1].join(" ");
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems JSON doesn't work. My javascript code stops on the line var arr = JSON.parse("[[0,'Apple','Banana'],['The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree', 'The Banana fruit, comes from Banana Tree']]");

Comment: YOu can use `eval("("[[0,'Apple','Banana'],['The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree', 'The Banana fruit, comes from Banana Tree']]")")` instead of `JSON.parse`, but I would not recommend it if your data is not from a trusted source.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `var arr = JSON.parse(str)` to convert your string to a Javascript array. Then access the members of the array nomrally, eg. `arr[0]`

Answer (score 1):

"looks like below in javascript" means you have an array of strings to me.

1. in the case you have this

   ```
   var myarray = [
              [0,'Apple','Banana'],
              ['The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree', 
               'The Banana fruit, comes from Banana Tree']
             ];
   ```

   just assign the array to a variable

   ```
   var first = myarray[0];
   ```

   for the second problem, use .join() method of arrays

   ```
   var second = myarray[1].join(' ');
   ```
2. or in case you have

   ```
   var mystring = "[[0,'Apple','Banana'],['The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree', 'The Banana fruit, comes from Banana Tree']]";
   ```

   then you'll need to convert to array first.

   ```
   var myarray = JSON.parse(mystring);
   ```

Comment: OP said that the data was in the form of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a =eval("[[0,'Apple','Banana'],['The Apple fruit, comes from Apple Tree', 'The Banana fruit, comes from Banana Tree']]");
var b = a[0];
var c = a[1];
```

now b and c are your new arrays;

you can also use the above method mentioned by mohkhan but it is not a valid json; if you have a valid JSON string then above one will be the preferred methos